# Problem in understanding how the operating system and memory works in a Unix system

Tags: process, memory, application

I am an undergraduate mathematics student and I am currently doing a course in operating system with a very little background in computer science.

Here are the basics that I know - An operating system has precisely 2 parts -

1. The file management system because everything in Linux can be viewed as a file
2. the device drivers that controls the harddisks and the other devices

Now,suppose we want to run an application  A ,  so the application A to get executed we need to load the executable file of application A from hard disk to memory.

Now this is my idea of how it gets done. I am not sure whether it's correct and I would really appreciate some help.

1. The file management system of the OS understands that to get application A executed we need the executable file of the application A from the hard disk whose address is provided by the file descriptor table(I am not sure but I think if I want to address file A.out whose address is say 2475 then in the file descriptor table I have a variable, say i which stores the address of the file A.out and the pointer from where the process will read from the file (is this the reason why the file descriptor table of different process are different? Where is this file descriptor table stored? Is it in RAM ?).
2. Now getting enough informations about what we should handle from where we proceed with an empty space say "buff"( a space in memory I assume)  and now probably the device driver which handles the hard disk will upload the information from hard disk from the given location and upload it into "buff" .

This is what I have understood. Pardon me if  my understandings are too much of a contradictions to the fact. Some help is needed and also some suggestions on how to clear my concepts.

Edit 1:Suppose I load the executable  file of an application  in the memory then I have a file descriptor which is actually an index of the number of files open we have opened when we were opening the executable file of the application, now this file descriptor points to a file table (there is only one file table in the kernel and which stores the details of files, say how many file descriptors are pointing to it and what mode it is in at that point and its ID(is it the address with respect to memory? ). It is possible for different file descriptors in different file descriptor tables to point to the same resource

Comment: Is this question about memory (as stated in the title), or is it about file-systems (as discussed in almost all of the body)?.

Comment: I really need some good book to study the os(something easy).I tried doing Silbershactz but not very fruitful .I am very lost , I need some guidance as the lectures are not helping me. Where do I start?How do I start?

Comment: This question is *really* highly opinion-based and not really a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you learned from your course, there are some serious doubts about the quality of that course. A full explanation of the functions of an OS and disk access is far beyond the scope of a Q&A site as this. So I will give you jst a short global explanation, from which much detail and nuances are missing. These are also gross simplifications.

An operating system does much, very much more than your two basic functions. It depends a bit on what the exact definitions of terms you use and what OS your looking at (Windows for example, includes a GUI in the OS), but the functions include at least:

- Job scheduling
- memory management
- file/filesystem access
- process management and process communication
- networking

So, going through your interpretations:

> The file management system of the OS understands that to get application A executed we need the executable file of the application A from the hard disk whose address is provided by the file descriptor table

Er, no. It is not the file-management system of the OS. Except from the first process (init in its different forms) processes are created by another process.  For example, if you do an `ls` from your terminal, the shell that you use asks the OS to load the program.

In Linux and Unix, the term "file descriptor" is probably something different from what is meant in your course; you should (at least for now) replace "file descriptor table" with "i-node table".

The file(system) function of the OS then searches the i-node table for the location of the file on the disk. The i-node table is a part of the file system and is stored on disk. However, the OS keeps a copy (cache) in memory to prevent unnecessary disk access.

So, what happens when you open a file? The user process does a file-open call to the OS, with the name of the file. The OS translate the name to the location on the disk (using the I-node table) and allocates a file descriptor for future reference to this file, until it is closed again.

Below, the device function of the OS tells the disc-controller to load certain sectors of the disk in memory, so the filesystem-function can translate it to a stream of bytes or blocks.

Comment: Suppose I want to open file A with address say 21 then the OS gets the address of file A in inode and what is the use of file descriptor then(in case of Unix) ?

Comment: A guess - a file descriptor stores the pointer(which points to the location from which it is currently reading from?)

Comment: I just googled a C file program example and I guess a  file descriptor is an address ,so I assume it is the address with respect to the memory then why would it be unique to different process.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Yes. I added that the fork-exec are also services from the OS, and that the description is a gross simplification.

Comment: @GuriaSona: No. Simplified, the file descriptor is used by the process to indicate it's access to the file. The file descriptor is not an address, it is an index in the file descriptor table.

Comment: @StephenKitt It is hard to simplify the wording so much that they will not be misunderstood and  yet remain correct. I put your words in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## I-nodes and file descriptors (simple version)

- A process looks up an i-node for a directory listing.
- It then uses the i-node to open a file.
- The open call returns a index into the file-descriptor-table.
- All other file-system calls use this file-descriptor.

The file-descriptor index is stored in the process in user-space.
The table is in kernel space (If you could edit it then you could subvert security). The fields in the file-descriptor-table will include the i-node of the file, the seek offset, read and write flags (can you read and or write), …

Every process has its own file-descriptor-table. It keeps track of what files this process has open. Permission checks are only done when the file is open, so the kernel has to track this. This is why the file-descriptor-table is in the kernel, and in turn why it exists (if there were no security, then the process could keep track it self).

Comment: I know it might sound stupid but I wanted to ask what is the work of processor in this whole process?Why are we taught all those x86 instructions and GCC calling conventions

Comment: The processor and memory, are different from the operating system. Probably best to learn separately. I would not learn x86 instructions. x86 is tough in the misconception that it is popular. However Arm is easier and more popular. The processor is what runs programs: it runs the kernel, and the processes. Memory is what holds programs and data, while the processor is processing them.